# Proper Writing Class in class

Tags: c#, oop

Assuming that there is a class of section of any government office (represented by Department class) and there is a class of workers (represented by Worker class). 
Is this structure of the code is correct?

```
    class Department
    {
        public int DepartmentId { get; set; }
        public string DepartmentName { get; set; }
    }

    class Worker 
    {
        public int WorkerId { get; set; }
        public string WorkerName { get; set; }

        private Department dept = new Department();

        public Department Dept
        {
            get
            {
                return dept;
            }
            set
            {
                dept.DepartmentId = value.DepartmentId;
                dept.DepartmentName = value.DepartmentName;
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: From which perspective? what is the intent?

Comment: The code in your `set` method of `Dept` is redundant, presumably you already have a `Department` object. You should just be able to do `dept = value`. You're probably better suited putting this on code review: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: This probably belongs on codereview.stackexchange.com as it is likely to have many different interpretations and "right" answers, and is not directly asking a question regarding programming but rather to class design.

Comment: This is probably more of a question for the Code Review site

Comment: Shouldn't workers share a reference value to a department rather than each have a copy of one?

Comment: One potential problem here is that two different workers who are part of the same department would return different instances of the department class. The department instance returned when querying the worker should return an instance of Department that exists outside of the worker instance.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 7):

> Is this form of the code is correct?

No, because it has unexpected behavior, from the caller's point of view. `Department` is a class, i.e. a reference type; so when you assign an instance of `Department` to a property of type `Department`, you expect to get the same instance back when you read the property. But in your case you just copy the properties to a different instance... Usually, with reference types, it is expected that if you do that:

```
Department d = new Department();
worker.Department = d;
d.DepartmentName = "Foo";
```

then `worker.Department.DepartmentName` will also be "Foo". But it's not true with your code, which is surprising for the caller; and you should avoid surprises as much as possible as it's a source of bugs.

Also, it's not easily maintainable, because if you add more properties to `Department`, you will have to update the code of the property.

Answer (score 0):

As Thomas points out, the Worker class should know nothing about the internal properties of the Department class.   If fact, since the ID & Name would be tied together, they should not be changeable.

```
class Department
{
    public int DepartmentId { get; private set; }
    public string DepartmentName { get; private set; }

    public Department(int id, string name)
    {
         DepartmentId = id;
         DepartmentName  = name;
    }
}
```

Hence, once you create a Department object, it will always have that name & Id.  All Worder in the same department can shared that same object:

```
class Worker 
{
    public int WorkerId { get; set; }
    public string WorkerName { get; set; }
    public Department Dept {get; set;}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That could be fine. I prefer to do my classes like this:

```
    class Department
    {
        public Department() {}
        public Department(int departmentId, string departmentName)
        {
            DepartmentId = departmentId;
            DepartmentName = departmentName;
        }
        public int DepartmentId { get; set; }
        public string DepartmentName { get; set; }
    }
    class Worker 
    {
        public Worker() {}
        public Worker(int workerId, string workerName, Department department)
        {
            WorkerId = workerId;
            WorkerName = workerName;
            Dept = department;
        }
        public Worker(int workerId, string workerName, int departmentId, string departmentName)
           : this(workerId, workerName, new Department(departmentId, departmentName)) {}
        public int WorkerId { get; set; }
        public string WorkerName { get; set; }
        public Department Dept { get; set; }

    }
```

This gives you the most flexibility in my opinion. Unless you are immediately doing something (calculations, etc) with the objects in your class, I prefer not to instantiate them internally, but only by assignment either via constructor or public property, so you always know what is in there. Just ensure any place you will be performing operations on Dept you check to make sure it is not null.

Comment: If I was writing this the ctor for `Worker` would be protected and you would have to work through the department instances public interface to work with the workers.